# include header in html

Tags: php, html

How could I include my header correct in my index file. I would like to have the posibilty to edit my header, since it is on all my pages.

Lets say I have a header:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
         </div>
    </nav
```

This code I have copied over to my header.php, so I only have once place to edit it. This above code should it be inside the body tag, or do I need to have the html, head and body tag in my header document?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <-!-- Code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do't understand what means «or is it not required to use html there», btw yes, should you put it in the body tag. [See more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)

Comment: Use include construction from php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container topnav">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>
     </div>
</nav>
   </body>
  </html>
```

I believe you are using BOOTSTRAP

Comment: Ah okay, so I also need to include the javascript, css etc on that page. I actually put it on my index page. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that all files containing PHP code, all your files should have the **.php** extension.

Then you can include whatever HTML particles you want like this: name the header file *header.php*, the footer file *footer.php: etc.*

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
     <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
       <-!-- Code here -->
     <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```